# PyMongo query - check if value exists or not

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm looking to perform a query on a database and extract some data to be processed. Here is my query so far:

```
pipeline = [{'$match':{"Timestamp":{'$gte':m(), '$lt':current()},

    'Frequency Survey Reference':{'$regex':'Ch2'}}},

    {'$group': {
        '_id': '$Timestamp',
        'Trace' : {'$push': '$TR Trace'}
    }},

    {'$sort': {'_id': -1}},

    {'$limit': 1}
    ]

get_tr = collection.aggregate(pipeline, allowDiskUse=True)
```

However, some of the records don't have any value for TR Trace (an empty array), and I want to perform a check where it ignores those entries and doesn't include them in the pipeline. How would I perform such a check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter them out as part of the $match with a [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) query operator:

```
pipeline = [{'$match':{"Timestamp":{'$gte':m(), '$lt':current()},
    'Frequency Survey Reference':{'$regex':'Ch2'},
    'TR Trace': {'$exists': True, '$ne': ''}}},

    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however that doesn't seem to solve the problem as it's still picking up the ones without anything in TR Trace. Would it be because TR Trace does exist in the object, and is just empty? I'm just looking to pick out the empty ones from my query, TR Trace exists in every JSON object, empty or not.

Comment: Thanks for the help!